# how to Set Minimum and maximum values for column charts in asp.net chart item control

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, charts

I have a problem with my chart control

problem: i what to change the axis of the chart dynamically when it is drawn..?
          I want to adjust the axis such that the x axis minimum is the value i want to start the chart with it and close till the maximum value i need ..?

FYI the chart type i am using is COLUMN.

So please tell me how should i try..?

I tried setting minimum and maximum properties dynamically but they take only double type but i what a date type according to data i want to display.

Thank you IN Advance

please send your answer if possible to rajekasani05@gmail.com

thnx
RK

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the points collection to a list of DateTime or anything you wish:

```
IList<DateTime> listx = new List<DateTime>();
IList<double> listy = new List<double>();

//iterate and add your values to the two lists: listx and listy

//when you're done, bind the lists to the points collection
yourSeries.Points.DataBindXY(listx, listy);
```

Hope this helps :)